# Unable to install driver software on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers

So I've been trying to connect my TI-84 Plus CE graphing calculator to my computer through the USB port... BUT I ran into a problem. It doesn't have a driver software apparently. I've tried both automatically and manually installing the driver that's required, but I kept getting "*This operation requires an interactive window station.*"

Image:

[image]

I've looked around the web for a solution and couldn't find one that would work for me. What is an interactive window station and where can I get it? Can I just override the need for it? Or is it necessary?

This is also not my first time running into this problem. Recently, I've tried to update my Nvidia drivers, but ran into this.

Comment: did you install your graphic card properly?

Comment: It came with my laptop and it just turns out that Windows Update isn't working and is getting errors. I also tried connecting my graphing calculator to another computer and it worked perfectly fine... Seems like something is wrong with the system in my computer.

Comment: run sfc /scannow using the command prompt as adminstrator, and then restart your computer and try Windows Update first, if is it working fine, run Windows update and install latest updates, then go and try to install your TI-84

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have a tool that usually fixes any problems with Windows Update. You can download it from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/windows-update-issues/en-us

Uninstall all previously installed drivers/software for your device, run it, restart pc, try to install again. Hope this helps :)